# MemoryError pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two data.frames using `pandas` however I am getting a **Memory error**. That could be a memory issue since my files have ~ 40,000,000 rows (`df1`) and 80,000,000 rows with 5 columns (`df2a`), however, when I tried to merge other similar file with 90,000,000 rows and 5 columns (`df2b`), the merging works.

Here is my code:

```
# Merge the files with pandas python
import pandas as pd

# Read lookup file from GTEx
df1 = pd.read_table("GTEx.lookup_table.txt.gz", compression="gzip", sep="\t", header=0)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace('rs_id_dbSNP147_GRCh37p13', 'rsid')

df2a = pd.read_table("Proximal.nominals.FULL.txt.gz", sep=" ", header=None, compression="gzip") # this file gives the Memory error
df2b = pd.read_table("Proximal.nominals2.FULL.txt.gz", sep=" ", header=None, compression="gzip") # this file merges just fine
df2a_merge = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2a, left_on="rsid",  right_on='rsid')
df2b_merge = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2b, left_on="rsid",  right_on='rsid')
```

I have looked to the amount of memory that each one of the files uses but `df2b` takes more memory but still merges just fine:

```
>>>print("df2a dataset uses ",df2a.memory_usage().sum()/ 1024**2," MB ")
  ('df2a dataset uses ', 3342, ' MB ')

>>>print("df2b dataset uses ",df2b.memory_usage().sum()/ 1024**2," MB ")
  ('df2b dataset uses ', 3470, ' MB ')
```

Also, the data types are the same in `df2a` and `2f2b`:

```
gene_id      object
rsid         object
distance      int64
n_pval      float64
nslope       float64
dtype: object
```

And this the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/users/jfertaj/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 54, in merge
return op.get_result()
  File "/users/jfertaj/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 569, in get_result
join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "/users/jfertaj/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 734, in _get_join_info
right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()
  File "/users/jfertaj/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 713, in _get_join_indexers
how=self.how)
  File "/users/jfertaj/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 998, in _get_join_indexers
return join_func(lkey, rkey, count, **kwargs)
  File "pandas/_libs/join.pyx", line 71, in pandas._libs.join.inner_join (pandas/_libs/join.c:120300)
```

BTW, I want to make an inner merging

Comment: `merge` is an inner-join operation, so the size of the result is determined by the size of the two tables _and the size of their intersection on the merged keys_. So, it's perfectly plausible that a slightly smaller table would give you a much larger join, if it just has more matching rows.

Comment: thanks @abarnert, any ideas to solve the memory problem? I have tried to do the merging with 100GB of RAM but still gets the same problem

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using a 64-bit Python interpreter, right?

Comment: I think so, I am using the python installed in a cluster, I guess is 64, is there any easy way to know which version I am using? 32- or 64?

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.maxsize)` is the most portable way. If it's 2147483647 or 4294967295, you're 32-bit; if it's 9223372036854775807 or 18446744073709551615, you're 64-bit.

Comment: yep I am 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [`dask`](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/docs.html) package for this type of large dataframes.
In particular, see its [DataFrame](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html), which is a way to handle large pandas DataFrames and parallelize the computations on it.

Your code could be modified to be like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

dd1 = dd.from_pandas(df1, npartitions=10)
dd2a = dd.from_pandas(df2a, npartitions=10)

dd2a_merge = dd1.merge(dd2a, left_on="rsid",  right_on='rsid')
dd2a_merge = dd2a_merge.compute()
```